# How to prevent Div from creating a new line

Tags: html, css

I am creating a menu bar using Div's. The only problem is that each div is vertically on top of each other due to its block style property, but I would like it to be a horizontal bar.

Here is my CSS code:

```
#homeButton{
height: 50px;
width: 125px;
background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Here is HTML code:

```
<div id="homeButton">
<p id="homeButtonText">Home</p>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
#homeButton{
height: 50px;
width: 125px;
background-color: lightblue;
display: inline; /*New Line of Code*/
}
```

When I use that, it doesn't make the div's line up, instead takes away the light blue color.

Comment: Are you looing at this: http://jsfiddle.net/crpnktdo/1/

Comment: I tried that, and it did not work. I do have a total of 8 menu items

Comment: Updated http://jsfiddle.net/crpnktdo/2/

Comment: @Jatin You should never use an `id` more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your CSS and use `display:inline-block;` I could also recommend using  `class` rather than `id` as you will want this style to apply to all the buttons in the menu. You should never use the same id more than once as the id is used to target a specific element.

If you want this to apply to all your menu buttons then I would do this...

```css
.menuButton{
height: 50px;
width: 125px;
background-color: lightblue;
display:inline-block;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
    <div class="menuButton">
    <p id="homeButtonText">Home</p>
    </div>
    <div class="menuButton">
    <p id="aboutButtonText">About</p>
    </div>
```

You might want to swap the paragraph `<p>` tags for anchor `<a href="link">Home</a>` tags. Anchor tags come with some default styles so if you want to remove the underline you can do this using `text-decoration:none;` you might want to also use `color:black;` as it will display blue by default.

Comment: That worked! But now the P inside the div isn't centered as I originally had them. Any idea on how I could fix that?

Comment: CSS Updated + recommendation for page navigation

Comment: I used the p tag as a temporary teg because I don't have all of my pages set up yet. The p suggestions made above didn't change anything.

Comment: Okay, well I wasn't sure if you knew about the default styles for anchor tags so I thought it would be relevant to explain with my recommendation of using anchor tags. I hope this helps. Happy coding :)